# UIPageViewController as sub view will disable main view events in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiview, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to use **UIPageViewController** to create walkthrough screens with three separate **UIViewController**s. As a summary, I have four View Controllers and a Page View Controller in my storyboard. One view controller act as base view (*XYZViewController.h/m*) and other three act as sub views that loads inside base view controller. Below shows how the *XYZViewController.h* displays roughly.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import “XYZPageContentViewController.h"
#import "XYZPageTwoContentViewController.h"
#import "XYZPageThreeContentViewController.h"

@interface XYZViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;

@end
```

Following code snippet shows the **viewDidLoad** method of *XYZViewController.m*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    XYZPageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 60);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    bottomView.layer.zPosition = 1;
    startBtnOutlet.layer.zPosition = 1;
}
```

Actually, loading sub views and walkthrough is working perfectly. What is not working is, the button touch up inside event I have declared in base view.

[image: App first interface]

As you can see with the image, there is "Start again" button at the bottom of the screen. At first that view even didn't display when I set page controller view till bottom of the screen and not using z-index option.

Which means having this line

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 60);
```

with commenting following lines.

```
// bottomView.layer.zPosition = 1;
// startBtnOutlet.layer.zPosition = 1;
```

What I need is limit the page view controller where the gray view begins and available the sub view till end of the screen. I can limit the page view controller frame as mentioned above, then it is apply to my all walkthrough screens as well. What can I do for that?

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/). Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

Keep comment below lines of codes.

```
// bottomView.layer.zPosition = 1;
// startBtnOutlet.layer.zPosition = 1;
```

Add this line below that code, inside **viewDidLoad** method

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:_pageViewController.view];
```